# Android. EditText dynamical change input type problems

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, autosuggest, android-inputtype

I have an editText for searching phone number. It automatically switches between two modes:

- entering phone number directly +7(900)000-00-00
- searching contact book

So, to do this a have to change editText input type dynamically, when user inputs text, following these rules:

1. When edit is empty: `INPUT_NO_SUGGEST`
2. When user input phone number: `INPUT_NO_SUGGEST`
3. When user input something else: `INPUT_TEXT`

The problem appears when entering text with suggestions:

- when I enter *Can* -> then click on suggest *Cam* it clears (*left gif*)
- when I enter *Can* -> then click on suggest *Can't* it works as expected (*right gif*)

[image: suggest-wrong] 
[image: suggest-ok]

In the 1st case we change word 'Can'->'Cam' and it works wrong
In the 2nd case we supplement word 'Can'->'Can't' and it works ok

Code inside textWatcher:

```
private static final int INPUT_TEXT = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
private static final int INPUT_NO_SUGGEST = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
...
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    boolean isPhone = isPhoneNumber(s);
    int inputType;
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        inputType = INPUT_NO_SUGGEST;
    } else {
        if (isPhone) {
            inputType = INPUT_NO_SUGGEST; 
        } else {
            inputType = INPUT_TEXT;
        }
    }
    editText.setInputType(inputType);
}
```

Have any ideas how it can be fixed?

Comment: have you tried removing `editText.setInputType(inputType);` line to make sure it is because of changed input type?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I suppose it's because of the `setInputType`, but the problem is I need to change input type to disable suggestions while entering digits and enable while searching for contact

Comment: firstly you need to be **sure** that it is because of `setInputType`. Then you may try to save `getText()` to the variable, do `setInputType`, and restore the entered text using `setText()`. Also you may try moving this code to `onTextChanged()`

Comment: @VladMatvienko i'm sure it is because of `setInputType`. I removed it and everything works fine. I also tried things you wrote. I logged each TextWatcher callback (before, on, after) and see that 'before': 'can', 'on': '', 'after': ''. So editText firstly clears, and inside my method  inputType changes to INPUT_NO_SUGGEST. So, suggest 'cam' is not applied.